# perl script: using Sleep() or Pause () to wait new updated data

Tags: perl, sleep

is there any method to write a program to wait the need update text file using `sleep()` function or `pause()` function? The program is hanging on execution stage and once the particular file is updated and the program will continue its work.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open (FILE, "/home/terrance/Desktop/perl/record.txt") || die "$!";

while(my $line = <FILE>)
{
        chomp($line);
        my $offset =0;
        seek(FILE, $offset, 1);
        print "$line\n";
        sleep(0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something like `tail -f`? If yes, try [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/~mgrabnar/File-Tail-0.99.3/Tail.pm)

Comment: other than File::Tail what else i can use?

Comment: Well, a simple `while (1) { sleep 1; defined ($_=<FILE>) or next; print $_; }` kinda works. But `File::Tail` is better.

Comment: I don't know, try it yourself. Also, `Tk` has its own timing facility so it's probably better to use it instead of system `sleep`.